# ILNumerics multiply complex with matrix<double>

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

I m looking at ILNumerics to translate some matlab code into c#.

How would I multiply a complex and a double?

Simplified description:

In Matlab:

```
A=[1 2 3] 
i*A*A'
```

Returns a complex number.

How would I do the same in ILNumerics:

```
        ILArray<double> A = ILMath.array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
        complex B = complex.i * ILMath.multiply(A,A.T);
```

Throws the error:

```
Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ILNumerics.complex' and 'ILNumerics.ILRetArray<double>'
```

**Update**

This works:

```
        double C = 14.0;
        complex D = complex.i * C;
```

But shouldnt:
    ILMath.multiply(A,A.T)

also return 14.0?

Comment: What complex number did Matlab return?

Comment: Matlab returned 0 +14.0000i

Comment: Matlab is outside of my area of expertise, and so don't know what operator * would do in that context, but did you perhaps mean to get the dot product of A and A' and multiply those? The dot product of A is 6.0, so that would yield 0+36i, which still isn't correct.

Comment: thank you ClickRick but I think they mean the same, * in matlab is teh matrix multiplication whereas .* is dotproduct. A = row, A.T=vector, so 1*1+2*2+3*3=14. No?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to make your array be one of `complex` values:

```
ILArray<complex> A = ILMath.array((complex)1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
```

The remaining question - that of multiplying a scalar by an array - boils down to what it means. The answer is that it is an array where each element of the original is multiplied by the scalar.

```
ILArray<complex> B = complex.i * ILMath.multiply(A, A.T);
```

B.ToString() is this:

> 0.00000+1.00000i 0.00000+2.00000i 0.00000+3.00000i
>   0.00000+2.00000i 0.00000+4.00000i 0.00000+6.00000i
>   0.00000+3.00000i 0.00000+6.00000i 0.00000+9.00000i

However, transpose the parameters to `multiply` like this:

```
complex B = complex.i * (complex)ILMath.multiply(A.T, A);
```

and the result is 0+14i, the same as from Matlab.

Comment: Thanks. The first part I get, I must use a complex array with only real parts (because my array is really a double). The second part I dont get at all. In my example A*A.T should return 14, how would I get a complex array back? This should only return one complex number. No?

Comment: ClickRick is right. `array(1.0,2.0,3.0)` creates a column vector. `multiply(A, A.T)` returns a matrix. If you transpose `A.T` you get the result you expect: `0+14i`

Comment: @HaymoKutschbach: But I do need to cast to double even if ILNumerics.ILRetArray<double> only contains 1 double, correct?

Comment: If you need a System.Double from a scalar ILArray, yes: you need to cast (double) or use `A.GetValue(0)`. It is not done implicitely since both variants can fail at runtime. (The other way around *is* implicitly converted: System.Double -> ILArray<double> however.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this works:

```
 ILArray<double> A = ILMath.array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
 complex B = complex.i * (double)ILMath.multiply(A.T,A);
```

and thus returns the same as Matlab

Comment: I get an ILCastException thrown with the details "Additional information: unable to convert array to scalar".